# How was this integration problem $\int \frac{\sec^2 x}{\tan x}\:dx=\log |\tan x | +C$ solved?

Tags: calculus, integration, indefinite-integrals

$$\int \frac{\sec^2 x}{\tan x}\:dx=\log |\tan x | +C$$

When I started working on the problem, I used $1 + \tan^2x = \sec^2x$, but that didn't get me anywhere. How has the problem been solved?

Comment: $\displaystyle \int \frac{f'(x)}{f(x)}\;{dx} = \log|f(x)|+C$

Comment: In most cases taking derivatives both sides is very helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Observe that
$$
\frac{d}{dx}\tan x=(\tan x)'=\sec^2 x
$$ giving, with the change of variable $u=\tan x$, $du= \sec^2 x \:dx$
$$
\int \frac{\sec^2 x}{\tan x}\:dx=\int \frac{du}{u}=\log |u|+C=\log |\tan x | +C
$$ for any constant $C$.

Comment: what does the apostrophe mean? Derivation?

Comment: @Guest Is it OK for you?

Comment: uh... not really. I get that integration of 1/tanx would be log|tan x|, but I don't see what the (tan x)' is doing there.

Comment: @Guest Let me edit my answer.

Comment: @Guest, the hint is that you should do integration by substitution using $u=\tan x$

Comment: OH!! Okay, got it, works perfectly. Can't believe didn't hit me. Thank you! :)

Comment: @Guest $(\tan x)'$ denotes the derivative of $\tan x$ with respect to $x$.

Comment: @Guest You are welcome.

Answer (score 0):

> **Hint**: $$\frac{d}{dx}(\tan x)=1+\tan^2x=\sec^2x$$